# Accessing the same file between two different WSL2 installations in Windows?

Tags: ubuntu, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I have two WSL2 installations, but I have a need to access/modify the same file on both of them.

My first thought would be that maybe I need to set up a samba share between the two of them; but I'm not sure which one is which ip on the interfaces in Windows.

Each installation is on a separate user account.

Is there an easier way to do this?

Comment: I suspect this would be better posted on [su] since it will likely require significant Windows knowledge that is not common here. I am not closing it since it isn't off topic, as such, but I would try asking on [su] instead of here, if I were you.

Comment: Saw this today; this was interesting: `PS Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\FileSystem::\\wsl$\Ubuntu\root\>`

Answer (score 0):

You could mount a shared public folder from windows in both WSL installations:

```
mount -t drvfs C:/Users/Public/share /mnt/share -o "rw,noatime,dirsync,mmap,access=client,msize=262144,trans=virtio"
```

Or put it in /etc/fstab for a permanent mount :

```
C:/Users/Public/share /mnt/share drvfs rw,noatime,dirsync,mmap,access=client,msize=262144,trans=virtio
```

Credits to:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59959090/how-to-mount-windows-folders-in-wsl-automatically-on-startup